# File ended while scanning use of \align

Tags: align

I am very confused. When I run the following code:

```
\documentclass[CJK,a4paper,openany,12pt]{cctbook}
 \usepackage{enumerate}
 \usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, mathrsfs}
 \usepackage[dvips]{color}
 \input vatola.sty
 \input amssymb.sty
 \begin{document}
 \begin{align*}
  &\left\{\frac{T}{n}>v,\frac{T_{an}}{n}\leq u\Big|Z_0=[bnx]\right\} \\
=&\left\{Y_n(v)>0,\sup_{t\leq u}Y_n(t)>a/b\Big|Z_0=[bnx]\right\}.
\end{align*}
 \end{document}
```

latex can run normally. The generated PDF looks like this:
[image]
I want to number the formula, so I use align like that:

```
\documentclass[CJK,a4paper,openany,12pt]{cctbook}
 \usepackage{enumerate}
 \usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, mathrsfs}
 \usepackage[dvips]{color}
 \input vatola.sty
 \input amssymb.sty
 \begin{document}
\begin{align}
  &\left\{\frac{T}{n}>v,\frac{T_{an}}{n}\leq u\Big|Z_0=[bnx]\right\} \\
=&\left\{Y_n(v)>0,\sup_{t\leq u}Y_n(t)>a/b\Big|Z_0=[bnx]\right\}.
\end{align}
 \end{document}
```

and latex has error:

```
Runaway argument?
 &\left \{\frac {T}{n}>v,\frac {T_{an}}{n}\leq u\Big |Z_0=[bnx]\right \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \align.
<inserted text> 
                \par
```

I have tried to test the following code:

```
\documentclass[CJK,a4paper,openany,12pt]{cctbook}
 \usepackage{enumerate}
 \usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, mathrsfs}
 \usepackage[dvips]{color}
 \input vatola.sty
 \input amssymb.sty
 \begin{document}
\begin{align}
  z &= (a+b)^4 \\
    &= (a+b)^2(a+b)^2 \\
    &= (a^2+2ab+b^2)(a^2+2ab+b^2) \\
    &= a^4 + 4a^3b + 6a^2b^2 + 4ab^3 + b^4
\end{align}
 \end{document}
```

but latex has the same error.
What should I do? Please help me!!!!

Comment: Why are you inputting sty files instead of using `\usepackage`? And what is `vatola.sty` that is not a known package.

Comment: The class you are using is non-standard as well. So unless you specify where we can get the class and `vatola.sty` we cannot help much.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [`vatola.sty`](https://github.com/OsbertWang/CCTinTeXLive/blob/master/cjcm/vatola.sty) at https://github.com/OsbertWang/CCTinTeXLive and I guess it's the one you're using.

Guess what? It has

```
\def\align#1\endalign{\def\tag{&}\plainvspace@\plainallowdisplaybreak@\plaindisplaybreak@
  \iftagsleft@\plainlalign@#1\endalign\else
   \plainralign@#1\endalign\fi}
```

which means that its `align` is completely different from `amsmath`s, as far as syntax is concerned.

***Don't*** load it, if you want to use `amsmath`.

And never do `\input amssymb.sty`.

Comment: Did you check the filedate on `vatola`? (`cjcm/vatola.sty`)

Comment: @daleif It's the least problem! 